# Is it possible to modify multiple VMs (all?) in one single vboxmanage modifyvm ... command?

Tags: virtualbox

**Context**

I have many VMs in my VirtualBox configuration.
Now I realized I would like to modify some VM settings on *all* my VMs.

**Question**

Is it possible to modify multiple VMs (all?) in one single `vboxmanage modifyvm ...` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible as [`vboxmanage modifyvm`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-modifyvm.html) takes only single `vmname` or `uuid` argument identifying exactly one VM.

What you can do instead is to write a script in language of your choice (bash, PowerShell, etc.) that will call [`vboxmanage list vms`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-list.html) to first retrieve list of all VMs and then loop over that list and invoke modifyvm command on each VM separately.